# Invalid Hook Call on a Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to find what causing the invalid hook call even though my hook is literally under a functional component. Maybe someone could literally pinpoint it for me an I am trying multiple way to remove this error.

Here is my Login.js

```js
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Browser,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import userDashboard from './userDashboard';
import adminDashboard from './adminDashboard';

function Login(props) {
const useValueGrepper = (initialValue) => { 
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
    
    const handleChange = e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }

    return {
        value,
        onChange: handleChange
    }
    }

  const employees = [ '00000000', '11111111'];
  const pass = [ 'user', 'user']  

  const employeeId = useValueGrepper();
  const password = useValueGrepper();


  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(employeeId || password === null){
      alert('Missing Entries')
    }
    
    console.log(employeeId.value);
    console.log(password.value);
  }

  return (
        
    <div className="App">
    <header className="posHeader">
        <div className='logoContainer'>
            <img src={logo} className='logo' alt="logo.svg" height='65px' width='80px'/>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div className="loginContainer" >
          <div className="loginForm">
            <div className="loginBanner">
              <h1>Sign In</h1>
            </div>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Employee Id</label> <br/>
                  <input type="employee" className="form-control" placeholder="Employee Id" autoComplete="new-employeeId" {...employeeId} pattern="[0-9]+" minlength="8" maxlength="10" />
              </div>

              <br/>

              <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Password</label> <br/>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" autoComplete="new-password" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" minlength="4" maxlength="32" {...password}/>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
              <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                  Forgot <a href="#">password?</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
}



export default Login;
```

Here's my App.js which was supposed to be my routes. I am not setting up yet any middlewares or etc.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './pages/login';
import userDashboard from './pages/userDashboard';
import adminDashboard from './pages/adminDashboard';

function App() {
  return(
    <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" render={Login}  />
            <Route path="/user" render={userDashboard} />
            <Route path='/admin' render={adminDashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error is pointed at

```
useValueGrepper
src/pages/login.js:15
  12 | 
  13 | function Login(props) {
  14 | const useValueGrepper = (initialValue) => { 
> 15 |     const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  16 |     
  17 |     const handleChange = e => {
  18 |         setValue(e.target.value);
```

Comment: Have you tried defining `useValueGrepper` outside of the `Login` function?

Comment: yep I've Tried. no I actually do it manually by setting each vairable on its own state rather than on a custom hook and the same issue still happen

Comment: Hooks can only be used in functional components, not in render functions. `<Route path="/" component={Login}  />`

Comment: oh @Thomas, sorry for the late Reply. I had it working with the component instead of render 2 days ago. I just forgot to open Stacksoverflow to see any replies. thank you for the reminder and advise btw.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of the hook should be outside of the functional component, you would be able to call/use the hook inside a functional components.

Comment: weird thing is that, when I put it inside the functional component, it work well when it is in the App the JS in the src, but when I move it to a dedicated page, the hook just causes error. im trying to put it outside the function rn.

Comment: @marcushighway it might be relevant what that error says.

Comment: I actually removed the hook and manually calling setState. even setState is on the top level of the function component, it throws the same Hook error.

Comment: function Login(props) {
    const [employeeId, setEmployeeId] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");